# Some products not showing up in magento backend but exist

Tags: magento

When am trying to search a product by sku for example "abc123" in backend then magento not gives any result but when am trying to find this in Global Record Search then magento give me a record of this product. I don't understand that actually where this product exist and from where i can found in backend?
and probably this product was added by quick product creation.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some more information about the exact searches you are doing?  Maybe some details about the backend and the entry you are looking for?  Is there anyone you are working with that is familiar with your setup?

Comment: thanks for reply. am using magento 1.7.0.2 yes am working my client. what further info you want about backend.

Comment: am trying to find this sku "CBM400E12-(2)-L530-AB" and product is exist with this sku.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the product configuration page and go to the inventory and set particular product qty as you want and select stock availability as "in stock"

I hope you solve your problem instantly.